# Convergence of arithmetic mean of bounded sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_n$ be a bounded sequence with converging arithmetic means $s_n=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k$. Does it follow that the sequence of exponential sums $e_n=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \exp{(a_k)}$ also converge?
Any thoughts appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The sequence $e_n$ may not converge.

Let $a_n=(-1)^n$ when there's integer k so that $2^{2k-1}\le n\lt 2^{2k}$
And Let $a_n=2\times(-1)^n$ when there's integer k so that $2^{2k}\le n\lt 2^{2k+1}$
So $s_n$ converge to 0.

But $e_n$ does not coverge. It swings between $ch(2)=\frac{e^2+e^{-2}}2$ and $ch(1)=\frac{e+e^{-1}}2$. The upper limit is $ch(2)+\frac{ch(1)}2+\frac{ch(2)}4+\frac{ch(1)}8+...$ and lower limit is $ch(1)+\frac{ch(2)}2+\frac{ch(1)}4+\frac{ch(2)}8+...$

Answer (score 1):

Let $(a_n)$ be the sequence given by $$0,0,1,-1,0,0,1,-1,0,0,0,0,1,-1,1,-1,...$$ where the blocks of $0$s and blocks of $1,-1$s keep doubling in size. The arithmetic mean tends to 0.

However, the arithmetic mean of $(e^{a_n})$ continually varies between $\frac{2+e^1+e^{-1}}{4}$ and $\frac{4+e^1+e^{-1}}{6}$.